# Not getting output when deleting a node at starting of doubly linked list

Tags: c, struct, dynamic-memory-allocation, doubly-linked-list, function-definition

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#define pf printf
struct node
{
    struct node *prev, *next;
    int data;
};
struct node *head = NULL;
//function to create a doubly linked list
struct node *create(struct node *head)
{
    int num;
    pf("Enter 0 to terminate :\n");
    pf("Data :");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    struct node *new, *ptr;
    while (num != 0)
    {
        new = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        new->data = num;
        new->next = NULL;
        new->prev = NULL;
        if (head == NULL)
        {
            head = new;
        }
        else
        {
            ptr = head;
            while (ptr->next != NULL)
            {
                ptr = ptr->next;
            }
            new->next = NULL;
            new->prev = ptr;
            ptr->next = new;
        }
        pf("Data :");
        scanf("%d", &num);
    }
    return head;
}
//function to traverse 
struct node *traverse(struct node *head)
{
    struct node *ptr;
    ptr = head;
    while (ptr != NULL)
    {
        pf("%d\n", ptr->data);
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
    return head;
}
//function to delete the head node 
struct node *delete_head(struct node *head)
{
    struct node *ptr;
    ptr = head;
    head = head->next;
    head->prev = NULL;
    ptr->next = NULL;
    return head;
}
//here i wanted to delete the head node but i am not getting the output but when i change //delete_head(a) to struct node*del=delete_head(a) and then traverse(del) i am getting the output //as correct. i am not able to figure it out.
int main()
{
    struct node *a;
    a = create(head);
    traverse(a);
   delete_head(a);
    traverse(a);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: After calling `delete_head` you need to set `a` with the function return value so that `a` becomes the new head. Your code is confusing in that there is a global `head`, a local `head` for each function and another head called `a` in `main`.

Comment: could you please refer any links or elaborate how can i change a to my new head.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters this declaration of global variable

```
struct node *head = NULL;
```

does not make a sense. Remove it. And in `main` write

```
struct node *head = NULL;
head = create(head);
traverse(head);
head = delete_head( head );
traverse( head);
```

The function  `delete_head` produces a memory leak because the node pointed to by the pointer `ptr` is not deleted. And moreover it can invoke undefined behavior when either the parameter `head` or `head->next` are equal to `NULL`.

And in `main` you have to set the returned value to `head` as already shown  above

```
head = delete_head( head );
```

The function itself can look the following way

```
struct node * delete_head(struct node *head)
{
    if ( head != NULL )
    {
        struct node *ptr = head;
        head = head->next;
        if ( head != NULL ) head->prev = NULL;
        free( ptr );
    }

    return head;
}
```

Comment: how will I deal if I had to create multiple linked lists and delete from them.

Comment: @SandeepGoswami It is enough to write in main for example struct  node *head1 = NULL; struct node *head2 = NULL; head1 = create( head1 ); head2 = create( head2 ); and so on.